# Bulk Text Editing

Tags: notepad++

How can I add certain character to the END of each row? With same spacing in between old and new column values across rows!

I tried `shift+Alt` to select multiple rows and using search --> Regular Expression --> $ Command I can bring cursor to end of each line irrespective of Size of each word.

But How to merge new column values near existing Column values with unique alignment across rows.

Is it possible in Notepad ++

```
Column 1 :

action             
usersessionid*
token
accountid
clientip


Column 2 :

Dinesh 
Kishore
Yuva
Vignesh
Ganesh
```

> Expected---------------

```
Merged Column :
action Dinesh           
usersessionid* Kishore
token Yuva
accountid Vignesh
clientip Ganesh
```

Comment: Does the Column 1 or Column 2 values can have spaces in between?

Answer (score 0):

When you've selected the values of "Column 2" with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Mouse drag:

- just copy the values <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- select a column right after the values in "Column 1" with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Mouse drag
- paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- delete the superfluous spaces with:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
  - Find what: `\h{2,}`
  - Replace with:          # a space
  - <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You task is possible using macro that will do the following.

1. From current row. Go to start of line (HOME).
2. Go down 10 rows (down arrow 10 times)
3. Mark all line (SHIFT-END)
4. Copy all line (CTRL-C)
5. Go back to origin line (up arrow 10 times)
6. Go to end of line. (END)
7. Add SPACE and paste marked data. ( SPACE CTRL-V)
8. Go down to beginning of next line. (down arrow, HOME)

Save the macro.

Run the macro again till satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to skip the manual `shift+Alt` selection, you may want to try with regular expressions and macros. Remember that macros can be saved for later reuse.

Record the following macro:

1. Press Record macro
2. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
3. Search: `^(?!Column \d)(\S+)(?=\h*$)([\s\S]*^Column \d[\s\S]*?)^([^\r\n]+)`

   Replace by: `\1 \3\2`
4. <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
5. <kbd>Find Next</kbd>
6. <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
7. Stop recording macro

Now you can play the macro with: `Run macro multiple times` button and then select: `Run until the end of file`

**NOTES:**

I'm assuming that first column data does not have spaces in between (like for example in `Customer Id`).

I also assume that `Column 1 :` and `Column 2 :` literals exist

Comment: If there can be spaces on first group of columns then It still can be done, but we need some extra steps on the macro. Just let me know.